# How to remove IIS coinhive malware attack 403 forbidden?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, http-status-code-403, malware

I'm running my .net core API on IIS server. When I call any endpoints of my API most of the time it works fine, but sometimes I get 403 forbidden error. From the browser I don't see anything in the response. But when I call using postman I get the following response from server.

[image: coinhive 403 error]

I have run malwarebytes, windows full virus scan to look for any malware attack. But that didn't solve the problem. I'm assuming some program or IIS configuration is causing this issue. Any idea of how to fix it or where to look is highly appreciated. I have looked at the installed programs, but didn't find anything suspicious.

Comment: You need to confirm all 403 responses coming from IIS. Enable FRT and see what it records, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Do you have any authenticate enabled in your application. Besides, I suggest you could also check your server to make sure you have set the right path for the asp.net core web api application and the right permission for your IIS application pool  to access the asp.net core's source file folder.

Comment: @LexLi: I enabled FRT but nothing gets written in log folder even after I am still getting 403 error.